# How to efficiently copy contents between two list controls

Tags: c++, mfc, listcontrol

I want to copy rows from one List Control to another List Control. I am only able to copy them by sub item. I think this is not very efficient. There must be a method to copy the content by rows. The following is my code that copies content one sub item at a time.

```
CString CurItem, tem, copystr;
int j = 0;
m_combo_list.GetLBText(m_combo_list.GetCurSel(), CurItem);
for (int i = 0; i < m_list.GetItemCount(); i++) {
    tem = m_list.GetItemText(i, 0);
    if (CurItem == tem) {
        m_report_list.InsertItem(j, _T(""));
        for (int k = 0; k < 14; k++) { // 14 items per row.
            copystr = m_list.GetItemText(i, k);// get one item per time from one list control.
            m_report_list.SetItemText(j, k, copystr); // this is another list control. Copy the item to this list control.

        }
        j++;
    }
}
```

Could anyone give a method to replace the for loop by copy a row from `m_list` to `m_report_list` directly? I think such a way must save a lot of time.

Comment: This is the only way to copy data between list view controls, but if you're concerned about efficiency you can use [Virtual List Controls](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/mfc/virtual-list-controls)

Comment: Good idea. With a virtual list control, the data would not be stored in the list control so it could be copied directly without calling any listview methods (except to update the visual representation of the target listview once after the copy is finished).